# What is isAuto intent's json property purpose

Tags: dialogflow-es

When fetching an intent from Dialogflow using APIv1, there is a property for userSays that is not define in documentation https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents

Its name is **isAuto** like in this example :

`"userSays": [
    {
      "id": "c768cb68-a946-4573-b404-2bffeef8d162",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "How much"
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "updated": 1519026688,
      "isAuto": false`

What is its purpose ? Is it linked to MachineLearning like intent's **auto**
property ?

Comment: Dialogflow documentation explains only for what `Auto` field is used & does not explain anything about why `isAuto` field is used in `user says` JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`isAuto` is used to indicate if the annotation of a entity was created by Dialogflow or a developer.  A `false` value indicates the annotation was created by the developer and a `true` value indicates that the annotation was created by Dialogflow.

In Dialogflow v2 this field name has been changed to [a `userDefined` boolean](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Intent#Part).  If the userDefined boolean has a value of `true` it means the annotation was created by the developer and if it is `false` it means the annotation was created by Dialogflow.